# Missing value in table visual when having 1 to many relationships in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 tables: Student ID, Student and the Score table:

| Student ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

| Student ID | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jennifer | F |
| 2 | Tom | M |
| 3 | Lexi | F |

| Student ID | Subject | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Math | 70 |
| 1 | Science | 80 |
| 2 | Math | 50 |
| 2 | Science | 65 |
| 3 | Math | 80 |
| 3 | Science | 95 |
| 4 | Math | 75 |
| 4 | Science | 65 |

This is how the Data Model looks like in Power BI:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBv29.jpg)

The student with ID 4 has missed values from the Student table and has scores in the Score table, but it looks fine when creating a table visual in Power BI, i.e., the ID 4 still have the sum of scores though having no values for Name and Gender:

[image]

However, data is always imperfect. It happens that student with ID 1 has a duplicated record, possibly due to a name change:

| Student ID | header 2 | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane | F |
| 1 | Jennifer | F |
| 2 | Tom | M |
| 3 | Lexi | F |

, and this changes the relationship between the Student ID and the Student table from '1 to 1' to '1 to many':

[image]

Then the sum of score for ID 4 is missing from the table visual:

[image]

Is there a way to add back the score for ID 4 with a duplicate in the student table?